# How can I disable the cursor animation in MS Office 2016/Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2016

The animated cursor that Microsoft have introduced in recent versions of Office drives me absolutely crazy - I simply must have it disabled. I am using Office 2016/Office 365 with Windows 7 and previously I had disabled the animation by following the instructions given in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1009313/799549.

However, it seems that something has updated overnight (it's a company-administrated work laptop) and now the cursor animation has returned. I've tried both of the suggestions in that answer (using the ../Software/Microsoft/Office/16.0/.. registry folder for Office 2016), but neither has worked and the animation has not been disabled.

Has anyone else experienced this with Office 2016/Window 7? Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-off-office-animations-9ee5c4d2-d144-4fd2-b670-22cef9fa025a), this seems to be a global Windows setting, which you can disable as follows:

1. Open the Ease of Access Center by pressing the Windows logo key + U.
2. Under Other options, click Play animations in Windows.
3. Close the Settings window.

This apparently disables all animations for all programs. Not sure if it is possible to only disable the smooth typing in Office 2016 though.

Edit: The above steps are for Windows 10, but the URL also lists the corresponding steps for Windows 7/8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I try it and see if it helps.

Comment: No, unfortunately this didn't work for me. The Outlook/Office cursor animation remains stubbornly difficult to disable ...

Comment: Hm, it's also just a workaround (if it does work), because then all animations in Windows are disabled. I wonder why they decided to implement this in Word since in Excel typing works/looks as expected.